# how to fix it?, css,js not render after validation in codeigniter,

Tags: javascript, php, css, codeigniter

In codeigniter when I check validation of login form, validations are okay, but cs and js are not rendered when click on the button with blank field or invalid data, after validation.

First image form is before validation.

This image is after validation which is not render css, js and background image...

[image]

Here is my code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Pay-Roll Login Form </title>

        <!-- CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,300,500">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/form-elements.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/img/backgrounds/1.jpg">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/img/backgrounds/2.jpg">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/img/backgrounds/3.jpg">

        <!--background image-->

        <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

        <!-- Favicon and touch icons -->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo base_url().'assets/ico/favicon.png'?>">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- Top content -->
        <div class="top-content">

            <div class="inner-bg">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 text">
                            <h1 style="color:#757575 ">
                                <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/img/logo/payroll.jpg" width="70px" height="65px" alt="logo"> <strong>ITab ERP</strong> Login
                            </h1>

                            <div class="description">
                                <p>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 form-box">
                            <div class="form-top">
                                <div class="form-top-left">
                                    <p style="font-family: arial">
                                        Enter your username and password to log on:
                                    </p>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-top-right" style="color: #e65100">
                                    <i class="fa fa-lock">
                                    </i>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-bottom">
                                <!-- codeigniter form style--> 
                                <!--<form role="form" action="<?php echo base_url().'Login_controller/index'?>" method="post" class="login-form">-->
                                <form action="<?php echo base_url().'Login_controller/index'?>" method="post">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="sr-only" for="form-username">
                                            Username
                                        </label>

                                        <?php echo '<div style="color:#d50000">'.form_error('username').'</div>'; ?>

                                        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username..." class="form-username form-control" id="form-username" value="<?php echo set_value('username'); ?>">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="sr-only" for="form-password">
                                            Password
                                        </label>

                                        <?php echo '<div style="color:#d50000">'.form_error('password').'</div>'; ?>

                                        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password..." class="form-password form-control" id="form-password" value="<?php echo set_value('password'); ?>">
                                    </div>

                                    <button type="submit" name="login" class="btn">
                                        Sign in!
                                    </button>
                                </form>

                                <div class="social-login-buttons">
                                    <a class="btn btn-link-2" href="#" style="background-color: #01579b">
                                        <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook
                                    </a>

                                    <a class="btn btn-link-2" href="#" style="background-color: #00e5ff">
                                        <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> Twitter
                                    </a>

                                    <a class="btn btn-link-2" href="#" style="background-color: #d32f2f">
                                        <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i> Google Plus
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 social-login">
                            <!--<h3>...or login with:</h3>
                            <div class="social-login-buttons">
                                <a class="btn btn-link-2" href="#">
                                    <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook
                                </a>

                                <a class="btn btn-link-2" href="#">
                                    <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> Twitter
                                </a>

                                <a class="btn btn-link-2" href="#">
                                    <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i> Google Plus
                                </a>
                            </div>-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <!-- Javascript -->
        <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/scripts.js"></script>

        <!--[if lt IE 10]>
            <script src="assets/js/placeholder.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you set your base url in config.php something like `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourproject/;'`

Comment: yes, i set my base url "$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/CI_payroll/';"

Comment: You have not provided a link to your first image.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7fV0.png this is my first image